# Does LinkedIn offer API where I am able to gather a users professional experience off their profile?

Tags: reactjs, linkedin-api

Looking into LinkedIn API and have only seen you can get access to r_liteprofile but that doesn't give me exactly what I'm looking for. I want to know if they offer an API which will allow to me to get the users professional experience and education.

Look into the LinkedIn partner program but not sure if that still exists.